# .NET MAUI Soft keyboard wipes out half the page on android why?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, maui

when soft keyboard pops up, it wipes out half the page like so on android 13. [Keyboard wipes out half the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLB2y.jpg)

i expect the keyboard to pop up and down without affecting the page . I've tried hiding my collectionView when keyboard pops up and Unhide it when keyboard goes down but it doesn't work very well. it only gets fixed when somehow it gets reloaded, like if i scroll the wiped section out of view and i scroll it back in

**UPDATE the problem was collectionView's ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"  and my project was on .net6 (didnt have any issues with the default ItemsLayout default which is VerticalList) but i upgraded my project to .net7 by going into csproj file in my project changing any reference to net6 with net7
hope it helps someone in the future!

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/?_ga=2.156635896.251634038.1677458536-1144270789.1675673660) with your solution(Updated section) and accept it as an answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Comment: okay thanks added it as anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i've explained in my post :

The problem was collectionView's ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" and my project was on .net6 (didnt have any issues with the default ItemsLayout default which is VerticalList).

I fixed this by upgrading my project to .net7, by going into csproj file in my project changing any reference to net6 with net7.

Hope it helps someone in the future!

Comment: Easier way to upgrade to .Net7, is via rt-click on Project in Solution Explorer /  Properties / Application / Windows targets / Target .Net Runtime => net7.0.