# .net Maui : ScrollView with KeyBoard Android

Tags: android, .net, xaml, mobile, maui

I have this page where the user enters the speed and percentage, I've set it up for the input to only show the numeric keypad and everything is working fine except for my ScrollView. Whenever the keyboard pops up it overlaps my page and I have to manually close it to see the button. How can I enable the keyboard rollover feature? If not, do I have a way to detect the keyboard and try to resize my page?

This is my xaml class.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="DoradSmartphone.Views.AvatarPage"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:DoradSmartphone.Models"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:DoradSmartphone.ViewModels"
         xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:DoradSmartphone.Helpers"
         x:DataType="viewmodel:AvatarViewModel"
         Title="{Binding Title}">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="EntryContainerStyle" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="48" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout x:Name="MainLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" RowSpacing="15">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Source="{x:Static helpers:Icons.AvatarXg}" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" />

                <Label Text="The Route Speed was 17km/h" FontSize="20" TextColor="RoyalBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20"/>

                <Entry x:Name="Speed" Placeholder="Type the speed" Text="{Binding Speed}" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource EntryContainerStyle}" Keyboard="Numeric">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <helpers:NumericValidationBehavior MaximumValue="30" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>

                <Entry x:Name="Percentage" Placeholder="Type the percentage of speed" Text="{Binding Percentage}" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource EntryContainerStyle}" Keyboard="Numeric">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <helpers:NumericValidationBehavior MaximumValue="100" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>

                <Label Text="{Binding NewSpeed, StringFormat='The new speed is {0} km/h'}" FontSize="20" TextColor="RoyalBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4" Margin="20"/>

                <Button Text="Send" WidthRequest="100" CornerRadius="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            Command="{Binding SetAvatarCommand}" Grid.Row="5" Margin="10" 
                            FontSize="15"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

My code behind page has nothing else but the BindingContext to my view model class.

Here's my view model class in case you want to check something else:

```
public partial class AvatarViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double speed;
    private double routeSpeed;
    private double newSpeed;
    private double percentage;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public double Speed
    {
        get { return speed; }
        set
        {
            if (speed != value)
            {
                speed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Speed));
                UpdateNewSpeed();
            }
        }
    }

    public double RouteSpeed
    {
        get { return routeSpeed; }
        set
        {
            if (routeSpeed != value)
            {
                routeSpeed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RouteSpeed));
                UpdateNewSpeed();
            }
        }
    }

    public double NewSpeed
    {
        get { return newSpeed; }
        set
        {
            if (newSpeed != value)
            {
                newSpeed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NewSpeed));
            }
        }
    }

    public double Percentage
    {
        get { return percentage; }
        set
        {
            if (percentage != value)
            {
                percentage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Percentage));
                UpdateNewSpeed();
            }
        }
    }

    public AvatarViewModel()
    {
        Title = "AvatarPage";
        RouteSpeed = 17;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void UpdateNewSpeed()
    {
        if (percentage != 0 || percentage >= 0)
        {
            var calc = RouteSpeed + (RouteSpeed * (Percentage / 100));
            NewSpeed = double.Round(calc, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }            
    }

    public ICommand SetAvatarCommand => new Command(SetAvatar);

    private void SetAvatar()
    {
        // Perform any necessary actions when the button is clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET MAUI Soft keyboard wipes out half the page on android why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75579282/net-maui-soft-keyboard-wipes-out-half-the-page-on-android-why). If you are targetting .Net 6, change target to .Net 7. If its still a problem, then try .Net 8 Preview: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4792. Though sounds like there is something broken in .Net 8 re this; may have to wait for an update.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no. First I forgot to mention, but I am already using .net7 because the google maps feature only works in this version, second I am not using any of the mentioned tags "collectionView's ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" since is just a simple form.

Comment: As a workaround, you can try to press the `Tab` key to switch focus.